# Where should the JsonSubTypes be read from?

Tags: java, json, validation, jackson, polymorphism

This question is piggy backing off of the other question I had posted as I'm looking for clarity on how the serialization / validation works with regards to the **JsonSubTypes**

Other question: [InvalidSchemaException using JsonSubTypes, not picking up what I defined in the base interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544714/invalidschemaexception-using-jsonsubtypes-not-picking-up-what-i-defined-in-the)

Let's say I have a base class **A**

A implements **BaseInterface**

If I have a sub class **B** that extends **A**, but implements it's own interfaces such as **AlpahInterface, BetaInterface, CharlieInterface**. Herein lies the issue as the validation fails because AlphaInterface only lists e.g. LAMA and so the validation does not know about all of the other types defined in the base BaseInterface.

Subclass **B** is only implementing whatever is defined by *AlphaInterface*, ignoring the fact it extends BaseInterface and also ignores the other implemented Interfaces and clearly not paying attention to the fact that B extends A which implements BaseInterface. I could verify this because I added to AlphaInterface all of the subtypes defined in the base interface and things work but I don't want to have to define in every single interface every possible subtype as they are not all relevant to the class that implement them.

I would have thought that either the extended A implementation would be picked up or all of the B implemented interfaces and not just the first one in the listing.

Please someone explain because all of the reading I have done the past two days online have not cleared this up for me. If anyone wants to open a discussion chat that would be great too!

Thanks.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = CatTopic.class, name = "CAT"),
  @Type(value = DogTopic.class, name = "DOG"),
  @Type(value = FishTopic.class, name = "FISH"),
  @Type(value = LamaTopic.class, name = "LAMA")
})
public interface BaseInterface {}

@JsonTypeInfo(
use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = LamaTopic.class, name = "LAMA")
})
public interface AlpahInterface extends BaseInterface {}


// Something to extend A
public class B extends A implements AlpahInterface, BetaInterface, CharlieInterface {}
```

Comment: Playing around with my code for the AlphaInterface, if I alter the JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME to JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS it is able to validate. Can someone point me to some good documentation on understanding what is going on with this Jackson stuff? I'm finding examples but that is based on the premise that you understand it already whereas I want to read up on the details of the functionality. Thanks

Comment: With the MINIMAL_CLASS the new items I created work but broke the old ones. Still trying to get this figured out. There are 3 of us working this problem and the only thing we can agree on is that whoever implemented this code of our did so in a way we cannot find being done in any example online. We are stumped. Not looking to alter the code base as we have an entirely new version of code and this is to be phased out and to do so would require the re-coding of 300+ files and who knows what other impact it may have. ugh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear as to where this code should be reading in the main listing of JsonSubTypes but I managed to get past my related posting problem.
Finally found the way to handle the main issue in my related post.
[public abstract @interface JsonTypeInfo](http://javadocs.okadatech.com/javadoc/jackson-1.9.10/reference/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html)

What needs to be done is for each of the Classes defined in the JsonSubTypes you must also specify on that Class @JsonTypeName("ClassName")
e.g.

```
@JsonTypeName("CAT")
public class CatTopic extends A implements AlpahInterface, BetaInterface, CharlieInterface {}
```